# bosun time depended alerts

Tags: time, monitoring, alerts, bosun

Good Morning.

I have been working with bosun monitoring application for the last few days and i like it a lot. But i need 1 thing that i am not able to get worked out.

I want to have 1 alert that response different depending on what time it is. So amount of logins to my site per hour in the day time needs to be 100 and at night time needs to be 10. When it falls below that i want to create a alert.

If i do that with 2 alerts the day time alert will go off at night. So i need to have a lookup that checks what time it is and then gives the correct threshold.

Anybody know how to do that.

Marcel Koert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bosun doesn't have this feature. I've considered it, but I have never been shown a necessary use case. Why?

There are two general cases I have considered regarding this:

- Some job or event runs at time X, and you don't want to alert because it expect certain things when that job runs. In this instance, it would be better to monitor the job, and not alert when the job is running. That makes the coupling more tight - so when you change the time of the job, the alert still won't false trigger.
- Things that vary throughout time. This is the case you are referring to if I am not mistake. When this happens, we see some *seasonality* to the data (In the following example, weekly seasonality):

[image]

To handle this case, we use anomalous alerts. Which effectively says something like "This is not what it was like at the same hour of the week for the past few weeks, send an alert". The key function for this is the [band](http://bosun.org/expressions.html#bandquery-string-duration-string-period-string-num-scalar-seriesset) function. Here is an example of doing this from [examples page](http://bosun.org/examples.html#anomalous-alerts):

```
alert slower.route.performance {
    template = route.performance
    $notes = Response time is based on HAProxy's Tr Value. This is the web server response time (time elapsed between the moment the TCP connection was established to the web server and the moment it send its complete response header
    $duration = "1d"
    $route=*
    $metric = "sum:10m-avg:haproxy.logs.route_tr_median{route=$route}"
    $route_hit_metric = "sum:10m-avg:rate{counter,,1}:haproxy.logs.hits_by_route{route=$route}"
    $total_hit_metric = "sum:10m-avg:rate{counter,,1}:haproxy.logs.hits_by_route"
    $route_hits = change($route_hit_metric, $duration, "")
    $total_hits = change($total_hit_metric, $duration, "")
    $hit_percent = $route_hits / $total_hits * 100
    $current_hitcount =  len(q($metric, $duration, ""))
    $period = "7d"
    $lookback = 4
    $history = band($metric, $duration, $period, $lookback)
    $past_dev = dev($history)
    $past_median = percentile($history, .5)
    $current_median = percentile(q($metric, $duration, ""), .5)
    $diff = $current_median - $past_median
    warn = $current_median > ($past_median + $past_dev*2) && abs($diff) > 10 && $hit_percent > 1
    warnNotification = default
    ignoreUnknown = true
}
```

Hopefully this path solves your alerting needs?

Comment: Each time series backend has it's own query functions. Graphite does have the `graphiteBand()` function however, which is documented in http://bosun.org/expressions.html#graphitebandquery-string-duration-string-period-string-format-string-num-string-seriesset . There is also an example of using graphite for anomlous alerts in the example as well at http://bosun.org/examples.html#graphite-anomalous-traffic-volume-per-country

Answer (score 2):

Using the `epoch()` function you can determine what time of day it is. Just mod `epoch()` by 86400 seconds per day and you have the second relative to the current day. Compare that to the start and end second of the time in UTC that you want your window to start and end.

This macro sets $during_business_hours to true if the time the alert is evaluated is between 08:00 and 03:00 UTC.

```
macro business_hours {
    $time = epoch() % 86400
    $start = 8 * 3600
    $end = 3 * 3600
    $during_business_hours = $time >= $start || $time <= $end
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `&&` instead of `||`?

Comment: No, because this crosses the midnight UTC boundary I want it to evaluate to true if the time is between 08:00 and 00:00 **or** between 00:00 and 03:00. Leaving the time between 03:00 and 08:00 UTC as a maintenance window where alerts will not trigger.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!